# How can i achieve this using css

Tags: css, sass, less

[This is look I'm trying to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ysD.png)

```
<ul>
    <li class="btn">A</li>
    <li class="btn" hidden>B</li>
    <li class="btn" hidden>C</li>
    <li >D</li>
    <li >E</li>
</ul>
```

or it can be like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="btn">A</li>
    <li class="btn" hidden>B</li>
    <li class="btn">C</li>
    <li >D</li>
    <li >E</li>
</ul>
```

and this too

```
<ul>
    <li class="btn">A</li>
    <li class="btn">B</li>
    <li class="btn">C</li>
    <li >D</li>
    <li >E</li>
</ul>
```

I tried css first and last child it did not work. button set need to appear as a group and first and last element need to be rounded, in some cases, the button group might have only two buttons, or just one. any advice ?

```
ul li.btn:first-child {
    padding-left: 7px;
    border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}

ul li.btn:last-child {
    padding-right: 7px;
    border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
}
```

Comment: ul{

list-style:none;
} 
li {
float:left;
padding:10px;
display:flex;
}

.inner-box {
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}


<ul>
    <li>
    
    <ul>
    <div class="inner-box">
    <li class="inner">A</li>
    <li class="inner">B</li>
    <li class="inner">C</li>
     </div>
     <li >D</li>
     <li >E</li>
    </ul>
      
    </li>
  
</ul>

Comment: Hi copy and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. This is what you are looking for:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 16px;
}

li.group {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

li.first {
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}

li.last {
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group first">A</li>
  <li class="group">B</li>
  <li class="group">C</li>
  <li class="group">D</li>
  <li class="group last">E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit** If you do not want the `first` and `last` class, this is a workaround

**NOTE: this only works in this specific case:**

- group of buttons is always at the start
- there is only one group, no other elements in between
- this actually **moves** element B to the back

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 16px;
}

li.group {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

li.group:first-child {
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}

li.group~.group~.group {
  border-radius: 0;
  order: 0;
}

li.group~li.group {
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  order: 1;
}

li:not(.group) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group">A</li>
  <li class="group">B</li>
  <li class="group">C</li>
  <li class="group">D</li>
  <li class="group">E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is more like it. can we do this without the first and last classes?

Comment: unfortunately there is no `first-of-class` or `last-of-class` selector, so this would be the simplest way

Comment: I added an option doing it without, but note that if you can avoid it you probably should

Comment: Wow.. amazing this is going to help me. thanks again

Comment: If the answer solves your problem and you do not need any additional help please consider accepting the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 16px;
}

li.btn {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul li.btn:first-child {
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}

ul li.btn:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="btn">A</li>
    <li class="btn" hidden >B</li>
    <li class="btn">C</li>
    <li >D</li>
    <li >E</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to group the list items no matter how many items available ?

i think this is what you need:

```css
.group,
.list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list>div:not(.group) {
  padding: 5px;
}

.group>div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.group>div:first-child {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.group>div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="group">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div class="group">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not really. just the ABC needs to be in the group and B should be hidden. Basically only the .btn needs to be grouped. Thanks for help

Comment: can you change the html structure ?

Comment: i have changed the answer. is this ok ? you can have multiple groups

Comment: this structure is a bit complex. plus structure can't be changed